# Why do my WCF class names have the parent class as part of their name?

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight

I've been experimenting with Silverlight-Enabled WCF services and I'm getting a strange behavior that doesn't happen in the tutorial I was using. I create a simple operation contract like such: (yes, I know there is no interface with everything defined, it's something that the Silverlight-enabled template does)

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[SilverlightFaultBehavior]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class TestService1
{

    public class TestResponse
    {
        public string Hello { get; set; }
    }

    [OperationContract]
    public TestResponse TestCall()
    {
        return new TestResponse();
    }
}
```

Then I go and create a reference to it like I would a regular WCF service. But when I go to use my defined classes:

```
ServiceReference2.TestService1TestResponse test = new ServiceReference2.TestService1TestResponse();
```

Whereas I'm expecting `ServiceReference2.TestResponse`. Any idea why my parent class name is being concatenated onto the front of my datamember class names? I added a service reference to a plain console application and the same thing happens, so it's not a silverlight related thing.. maybe some setting in Silverlight-enabled WEC services? I watched this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ln2LyWvf6Q to see if it happened for others, but it looks like the class names work fine there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of luck I discovered what the issue was. I need to have the TestResponse class declared outside of the TestService1 class. I'm a little surprised the code generator for creating service references creates the classes in this way. I'd expect a `ServiceReference2.TestService1.TestResponse` instead, which is what threw me off so much.